# Connection closed on port 22 digital ocean droplet

Tags: ssh

after `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` i rebooted my droplet, and now I cannot SSH into it, I get the following error message `Connection closed by ??.??.??.?? port 22`. How can I identify the problem?

Comment: Have you logged into directly and examined the logs?